# param is missing or the value is empty rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a 3 views, with create form, but  a sample    def new def create works good, but other def not works...

## RateFormController.rb

```
class RateFormController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @rateform = RateForm.new
    end

    def create
      @rateform = RateForm.new(rate_params)
      if @rateform.save
        redirect_to :root
        RateFormMailer.rate_email(@rateform).deliver_now
      end
    end

    def encreate
       @rateform = RateForm.new(rate_params)
        RateFormMailer.rate_email(@rateform).deliver_now
       # ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now
    end

    def rucreate
       @rateform = RateForm.new(rate_params)
       if @rateform.save
        redirect_to :root
        RateFormMailer.rate_email(@rateform).deliver_now
        end
    end



  private
    def rate_params 
      params.require(:rate_form).permit(:name, :mail, :comment, :ratename, :phone)
    end

end
```

## 127.0.0.1:3000/rate_form/encreate

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in RateFormController#encreate
>      param is missing or the value is empty: rate_form

Comment: Please add your routes

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/23eaa5a82f3661cbd3f9b47a3d8cf437  this is my routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they are empty because you were using `GET` method for them

```
 rate_form_encreate_path    GET /rate_form/encreate(.:format)   rate_form#encreate
 rate_form_rucreate_path    GET /rate_form/rucreate(.:format)   rate_form#rucreate
```

These are your routes of `GET` type

Please change them to `POST` type.

```
match '/rate_form/encreate' => 'rate_form#encreate', via: [:post], :as => :rate_form_encreate
match '/rate_form/rucreate' => 'rate_form#rucreate', via: [:post], :as => :rate_form_rucreate
```

Updated:

```
match '/rate_form/ennew' => 'rate_form#ennew', via: [:get], :as => :rate_form_ennew
match '/rate_form/runew' => 'rate_form#runew', via: [:get], :as => :rate_form_ennew
```

Comment: i did it, after that i should create the new a copy of def new? right?

Comment: Yes, You have to do that

Comment: i did a   def runew
            rateform = RateForm.new
        end 
 &&  def ennew
          rateform = RateForm.new
        end      

after that i should make a routes again... i dont know what  i should adding

Comment: Just create the method and then add following in your routes

Comment: and how do I then will integrate def ennew & def encreate

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following routes in `routes.rb` file

```
resources :rate_forms do
  get :encreate
  get :rucreate
end
```